# Internet explorer and %

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, mozilla

Does someone know how I can use a % on the height and width of an image?

On Chrome, Mozilla, Safari and Opera it works fine, but on Internet Explorer sometimes it shows me the images with 100%, other times with 160% ... every time that I refresh the page it shows me a random heigth/width...

I used it:

HTML:

```
 <td><img class=test src='./prov.jpg'/></td>
```

CSS:

```
.test{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you are missing apostrophes around your class name. It should be `<td><img class="test" src='./prov.jpg'/></td>` Maybe it won't fix the problem but having valid markup is always a good start at fixing parsing errors.

Answer (score 0):

The 100% height and width you apply depends on the container of the image (*in this case the `td` element*).

Comment: The problem is that the <td> works with % too. For example `<td style='width:20%;height:20%;'></td>` Then I have the same problem :(